# Filter records for Dropdown control

Tags: dropdown, powerapps

How can I filter rows for my Dropdown control?

Currently I'm binding Items property to column e.g. `Items=Table1.Name`
but this populates dropdown with all possible rows. I want to filter all rows in which another column meets condition e.g. `Table1.Date=Today()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Filter` expression in the `Items` property of your dropdown control:

```
Items: Filter(Table1, Date = Today())
```

And you can select which field of your table to show in the dropdown by using the Advanced view (in the case below, `Name`, as you had in your example):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that I had to do something a little more complex for filtering out results for a SQL source where I also needed a Distinct.

The basic idea is I wanted years out of a table, but only last year and whatever years we had listed. Also worth noting the 500 row limit was a bit of an issue against my original date table, and so this only works with smaller tables.

In my case, I needed to create a view to reduce the data granularity

```
Distinct(Filter('[dbo].[YearList]', YearNumber >= Year(Now()) -1),  YearNumber)
```